# Registration Page does not record user data with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //create variables
    private EditText mUsername, mPassword, mEmail, mPhone;
    private Button mRegister;
    private TextView mLogin;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ImageView mProfilePicture;
    String user_email, user_name, user_phone, user_password;

    //on creation of activity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        setupViews();

        //firebase instance declared
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //When register is clicked
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //if all fields are okay using validation method
                if(validate()){
                    //get user info
                    String user_email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_phone = mPhone.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_name = mUsername.getText().toString().trim();

                    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                sendEmailVerification();
                                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        //Return user back to login page
        mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }


    //setup views by id from xml
    private void setupViews(){
        mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNewUsername);
        mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNewPassword);
        mEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNewEmail);
        mPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
        mLogin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin);
        mProfilePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewProfilePicture);
    }

    //validate if all fields are okay and not empty
    private Boolean validate() {
        Boolean result = false;

        //convert inputs to strings
        String user_name = mUsername.getText().toString();
        String user_password = mPassword.getText().toString();
        String user_email = mEmail.getText().toString();
        String user_phone = mPhone.getText().toString();

        //check if any fields are empty, if not then return result
        if (user_name.isEmpty() || user_password.isEmpty() || user_email.isEmpty() || user_phone.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "All fields are required for registration.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
    private void sendEmailVerification(){
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(firebaseUser!=null){
            firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        sendUserData();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Successfully Registered, Verification mail sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mAuth.signOut();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Verification mail has'nt been sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void sendUserData(){
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(user_phone, user_email, user_name);
        myRef.setValue(userProfile);
    }
}
```

Solved the crash with my profile page and got it to save artifical data, but found out my registration page is the problem and is not recording data. Here is my Userprofile.java for reference

```
public class UserProfile {
    public String user_phone;
    public String user_email;
    public String user_name;

    public UserProfile() {
    }

    public UserProfile(String user_phone, String user_email, String user_name) {
        this.user_phone = user_phone;
        this.user_email = user_email;
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }

    public String getUser_phone() {
        return user_phone;
    }

    public void setUser_phone(String user_phone) {
        this.user_phone = user_phone;
    }

    public String getUser_email() {
        return user_email;
    }

    public void setUser_email(String user_email) {
        this.user_email = user_email;
    }

    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }

    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, i'd read extensively on the topic and can't seem to see whatever small issue is causing the hold-up. Any other pointers are also welcome.

Comment: please add UserProfile.java and screenshot of your firebase database.

Comment: Added both of those.

Comment: Your firebase structure does not show any uid, yet you use it to create the reference to which you attach your listener. You're not accessing the right path.

Comment: Thank you Levi, I've found out the issue was my registration code. Do you see what might be the issue?

Comment: Please add a completionlistener to where you are trying to save the data in firebase to see if you are getting any errors. And include any errors in this question

Comment: The data saving in firebase is added as a result of an oncompletelistener, you want me to add a second?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    UserProfile userProfile = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
    assert userProfile != null;
    mProfileName.setText(userProfile.getUser_name());
    mProfileNumber.setText(userProfile.getUser_phone());
    mProfileEmail.setText(userProfile.getUser_email());
}
```

With:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    UserProfile userProfile = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
    if(userProfile != null){
        mProfileName.setText(userProfile.getUser_name());
        mProfileNumber.setText(userProfile.getUser_phone());
        mProfileEmail.setText(userProfile.getUser_email());
    }
}
```

Comment: This stopped the crash, but the data still does not update.